# REP-52005: The specified key does not exist in the key map file

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration, plsqldeveloper, oraclereports

This is the procedure which is using to call the report on web browser.

```
PROCEDURE proc_call IS
    rep_url        VARCHAR2(2000);
    to_date1       VARCHAR2(12);
    destype1       VARCHAR2(15);
    desformat1     VARCHAR2(15);
    copies         NUMBER(3);
    desname1       VARCHAR2(25);
    userid1        VARCHAR2(5);
    the_username   VARCHAR2(25);
    the_password   VARCHAR2(25);
    the_connect    VARCHAR2(25);
BEGIN
    the_username := get_application_property(username);
    the_password := get_application_property(password);
    the_connect := get_application_property(connect_string);
    to_date1 :=:fertrake_receipt.select_month
     ||  :fertrake_receipt.select_year;
    destype1 :=:fertrake_receipt.destype;
    desformat1 :=:fertrake_receipt.desformat;
    copies :=:fertrake_receipt.copies;
    userid1 :=:fertrake_receipt.userid;
    rep_url := '/reports/rwservlet?&userid&report=details_outstanding_private_trade.jsp&destype='
     ||  destype1
     ||  '&desformat='
     ||  desformat1
     ||  '&copies='
     ||  copies
     ||  '&MONTH_YY='
     ||  to_date1
     ||  '&userid1='
     ||  userid1
     ||  '&paramform=no';

    web.show_document(rep_url,'_blank');
END;
```

and the below code is written on when button pressed trigger on button and above procedure used in below code.

```
DECLARE
    al_id       alert;
    al_button   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    IF :fertrake_receipt.select_month IS NULL THEN
        al_id := find_alert('Alert_message');
        set_alert_property(al_id,alert_message_text,'Enter A Valid MONTH');
        al_button := show_alert(al_id);
        RAISE form_trigger_failure;
        go_item(:fertrake_receipt.select_month);
    END IF;

    proc_call;
END;
```

but when i press the button to execute the report
it gives error 
REP-52005: The specified key  does not exist in the key map file.

i searched on google that how to specifie key in CGICMD file please help what exect entry i have to do in cgicmd

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

CGICMD line for a report should look like this:

```
my_report: server=rep_ias report=my_report.rdf userid=username/password@ora11g destype=cache desformat=PDF %0 %1 %2 %3 %4 %5
```

When calling the report, you'd only mention its "alias" or "key" mentioned in the error message (it is the first word in that line, "my_report"; although you can name it any way you want, it is easier to keep it the same as .RDF filename).

- Server is name of your report server.
- Userid contains credentials used to connect to the database.
- %0 %1 %2 etc. represent parameters; you can use up to %9, which means 10 parameters in total